# Find "Network" IP adresses with SWIFT

Tags: swift, networking, ip

I try to find the IP adresse of a Raspberry PI (LINUX) that is connected to the same Network as the iOS device my code is running on.
Is there some way to "find all" ip adress in the network the device is currently joined via SWIFT?

Answer (score 1):

If you ping the broadcast address, unless devices are specifically configured not to replay, they will do so. How you do that with Swift is another question.

This question+answer will work if you know your IP address, you need to probe all the probable addresses of course.

[How to check Internet is working or not in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698052/how-to-check-internet-is-working-or-not-in-ios)

Comment: yes thats the way i wanted to go, i could send the ping but cant find out "how to get the returns"